# Oracle 11. Updating BLOB field. Db file sequential read inappropriately slow?

Tags: oracle, performance, jdbc, java

I've and Oracle (11 Enterprise) schema with a table

```
 CREATE TABLE USER.WSP_BUNDLE ( 
    NODE_ID     RAW(16) NOT NULL,
    BUNDLE_DATA BLOB NOT NULL 
    );
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX USER.WSP_BUNDLE_IDX ON USER.WSP_BUNDLE(NODE_ID);
```

and 3'rd party library (Java 6, JDBC - latest jdbc driver) that manipulate it.

Oracle profiler (tkprof) shows that **about 50% of overall time the lib execute such statement**:

```
update WSP_BUNDLE set BUNDLE_DATA = :1 where NODE_ID = :2
```

TKProf data

```
Plan Hash: 4085453680
update WSP_BUNDLE set BUNDLE_DATA = :1  where NODE_ID = :2 


call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse      264      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute    400     30.59     382.88     141451    1623163    3233827         400
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total      664     30.59     382.88     141451    1623163    3233827         400

Misses in library cache during parse: 0
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 87  

Rows     Row Source Operation
-------  ---------------------------------------------------
      0  UPDATE  WSP_BUNDLE (cr=8753 pr=707 pw=706 time=0 us)
      1   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN WSP_BUNDLE_IDX (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=104 card=1)(object id 75730)


Elapsed times include waiting on following events:
  Event waited on                             Times   Max. Wait  Total Waited
  ----------------------------------------   Waited  ----------  ------------
  db file sequential read                    141251        5.53        328.04
  direct path write                             402        0.09          0.43
  SQL*Net more data from client              142158        1.04         11.89
  direct path read                              200        0.03          0.07
  Disk file operations I/O                        1        0.00          0.00
  SQL*Net message to client                     400        0.00          0.00
  SQL*Net message from client                   400        0.29          0.50
  log file switch (private strand flush incomplete)
                                                  5        0.05          0.23
  asynch descriptor resize                   139723        7.46          8.57
  buffer busy waits                               2        0.00          0.00
  log file switch (checkpoint incomplete)         3        0.18          0.27
  log file sync                                   2        0.00          0.00
```

Could anybody explain/hint me what's going on? Why the update is so slow?

The table WSP_BUNDLE contains about 200+k rows. At the same time I've other tables in the same schema with blobs (CLOB to be more concrete) that contains 600+k rows where similar updates work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already answered at a parallel thread on serverfault:  https://serverfault.com/questions/345253/oracle-11-updating-blob-field-db-file-sequential-read-inappropriately-slow/345588#345588

> In Oracle, LOB (including BLOB) is stored as:
>
> - in-the-table LOB - if the LOB is smaller than 3900 bytes it can be stored inside the table row; by default this is enabled, unless you
>     specify DISABLE  STORAGE IN ROW
> - normal LOB - stored in a separate segment, outside of table, you may even put it in another tablespace; for these:
>
>   - a minimum of CHUNK bytes are allocated and entirely redo-logged (even if LOB has only 1 byte)
>   - there is an internal intermediate index behind a LOB column, which gets contentious on updates and may practically serialize them
>   - access is multi-level and thus relatively slower
>   - with NOCACHE option, the waiters are "direct path read" - the default
>   - with CACHE option, the waiters are "db file sequential read"
>
>     - where CACHE_SIZE_THRESHOLD is not taken into account, so a large LOB can waste your cache
>
> Therefore, if your LOBs are larger than 4 kB they will get relatively
>   slow, and this may simply be your case. I would examine the sizes.
>
> I would examine USER_LOBS (or DBA_LOBS) to see how the "good" and
>   "slow" LOB columns differ in their definitions.
>
> The Metalink note ID 66431.1 describes this and may be of interest to
>   you, if you have access there.

**UPDATE** - see link above, I've had some thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using LOB SecureFile -- Basic will generate loads of sequential reads -- with or without prior DELETE.